# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}(\omega+\nu)^{(n+1)}z^\nu{_2F_1}(1,\omega+\nu+1;n+2;1-z)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function, zeta-functions, stirling-numbers

I recently found a proof for the following sum
\begin{align*}
S_n & =\sum_{k=0}^n\mathcal S_n^{(k)}(\Phi(z,-k,\omega)-z^\nu\Phi(z,-k,\omega+\nu))\\ & =\frac{1}{n+1}(\omega+\nu)^{(n+1)}z^\nu{_2F_1}(1,\omega+\nu+1;n+2;1-z),
\end{align*}
where $\mathcal S_n^{(k)}$ are Stirling numbers of the 1st-kind, $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the Lerch transcendent, $(s)^{(n)}=\Gamma(s+1)/\Gamma(s-n+1)$ is the falling factorial, and ${_2F_1}(\cdot)$ is the hypergeometric function.

My question is about finding an expression for $S=\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n$.  If we restrict $z\in(0,1)$ each of the special functions listed may be represented as a convergent power series which may aid in this calculation. The r.h.s. then becomes
$$
S=z^\nu\Gamma(\omega+\nu+1)\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{1}{\Gamma(\omega+\nu-n)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(\omega+\nu+1)_k}{(n+2)_k}(1-z)^k.
$$
Its not immediately obvious to me what happens with the $\Gamma(\omega+\nu-n)$ term as $n$ becomes large and this is where I got stuck.  How to proceed?

Comment: You have some problems in your last expression for $S$. The subscript in the sum for $(\omega +\nu+1)$ should be $k$. Also where did $(\omega+\nu)^{n+1}$ go?

Comment: @Gary Thank you. I fixed the subscript. The $(\omega+\nu)^{(n+1)}$ was rewritten as a ratio of Gamma functions per the definition.

Comment: Ah, I see, it is not a power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [(15.12.3)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.12.E3) and [(5.11.13)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.E13), we have
\begin{align*}
S_n & = \frac{1}{{n + 1}}(\omega  + \nu )^{(n + 1)} z^\nu  \frac{{\Gamma (n + 2)}}{{\Gamma (n - \omega  - \nu  + 1)}}\frac{1}{{n^{\omega  + \nu  + 1} }}\left( {1 + \mathcal{O} \! \left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right)
\\ & = (\omega  + \nu )^{(n + 1)} z^\nu  \frac{{\Gamma (n + 2)}}{{\Gamma (n - \omega  - \nu  + 1)}}\frac{1}{{n^{\omega  + \nu  + 2} }}\left( {1 + \mathcal{O} \! \left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right)
\\ & = z^\nu  (\omega  + \nu )^{(n + 1)} \frac{1}{n}\left( {1 +\mathcal{O} \! \left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right)
\\ & = ( - 1)^{n+1} \frac{{z^\nu  }}{{\Gamma ( - \omega  - \nu )}}\frac{{\Gamma (n - \omega  - \nu )}}{n}\left( {1 + \mathcal{O} \! \left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right).
\end{align*}
If $\omega+\nu$ is not a non-negative integer, $S_n$ will tend to infinity in absolute value and will oscillate in sign.